# What is the significance of mirrors in Russian Doll?

Tags: analysis, russian-doll

Every time Nadia and Alan die in [Russian Doll](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7520794/?ref_=nv_sr_1) they reappear in front of a mirror. With all their differences this is a new starting point for both of them. Why a mirror? Why not in front of a window, or in bed?
I found this very curious. Was this supposed to be a way of making them face themselves, and their fears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are symbolic. They are the subjects of one of the sections in [this explanation of the show by IndieWire](https://www.indiewire.com/2019/02/russian-doll-emily-of-new-moon-psychic-death-falling-cats-netflix-1202044837/):

> **Mirrors, reflections, and how one perceives one’s identity or
>   narrative also comes up multiple times in “Russian Doll.”**  In one
>   scene, Aunt Ruth recounts an incident from Nadia’s past to Alan.
>   “Don’t get me started on the mirrors,” Ruth says. “One day, [Nadia’s
>   mother] shattered them, and when I came to take Nadia to school, the
>   mirrors were gone and there was glass everywhere.”

This is in the sixth episode, and the next lines in particular offer a clue:

> “Why mirrors?” Alan asks. **“Reflection, proof of existence, another
>   pair of eyes,” Ruth explains. “That’s why therapists are important.
>   Without them, we are very unreliable narrators of our own stories.”**

The disappearance of the mirrors is actually an important plot point:

> Both Alan and Nadia come back to life in the same place – in front of
>   their respective bathroom mirrors, and **Nadia knows something is going
>   wrong when the mirrors begin to disappear from her timeline**. Like
>   Emily, it’s up to her to adjust what she perceives her next steps to
>   be. The ultimate example of how not reflecting on the past or
>   relationships can haunt her occurs during her diner death, right after
>   she gives the girl Lucy (Tatiana E. Rivera) a copy of “Emily of New
>   Moon.” Nadia begins to cough up blood and eventually… a shard from a
>   mirror emerges from her mouth. Not dealing with the reality of her
>   crappy mother is hurting her in the most literal way possible.

Mirrors appear also in other scenes:

> Even the womanizing literature professor Mike (Jeremy Lowell Bobb) is
>   affected by a loss of reflection. When Alan bursts into the
>   philanderer’s office, pummels him, and then shatters a mirror, Mike is
>   left visibly flustered. He asks his student how his face looks and
>   adds, “The mirror’s gone. I can’t tell.” Even though he’s unwilling to
>   admit it, **the attack makes him reflect on his part of the infidelity**
>   by sleeping with Alan’s girlfriend and the hurt he had caused. If he
>   is to accept the ladies’ man side of himself, he also needs to accept
>   the morally grey side of himself in the partners he chooses.

Note the multiple meanings of "reflection".